# NetCDF NF90_PUT_VAR returns error status -51 and the file is empty

Tags: fortran, netcdf

I want to write the data of a 3D variable calculated by Fortran routines into a NetCDF file.
I have written the code to write the variable data but it is creating an empty NetCDF file after the execution.

```
stat = NF90_CREATE( '/home/sachin/output.nc', NF90_CLOBBER, ncid_user)

stat = NF90_DEF_DIM( ncid_user, i, NF90_UNLIMITED, i_id )
stat = NF90_DEF_DIM( ncid_user, j, NF90_UNLIMITED, j_id )
stat = NF90_DEF_DIM( ncid_user, k, NF90_UNLIMITED, k_id )

    e_id=(/i_id,j_id,k_id/)     

stat = NF90_DEF_VAR( ncid_user, ene, NF90_INT, e_id, ev_id )


stat1 = NF90_OPEN('/home/sachin/output.nc', NF90_WRITE, ncid_user)

stat1 = NF90_PUT_VAR(ncid_user, ev_id, start = (/ 1,1,1 /), count = (/ 10,10,0 /), stride = (/ 10,10,0 /) )
```

When I am printing `stat1` variable, it is printing `-51` as the return value of the `NF90_PUT_VAR` function.

Comment: Have you checked the values of `stat` and of `stat1` at each step ?

Comment: You can use the `NF90_STRERROR` routine to translate an error code into a more useful string. In this case, -51 means "Unknown File Format"

Comment: But here's what I'm wondering: Are you closing the file before re-opening it again? I can't see that from your snippet.

Comment: Heaps of problems here. Which value of `stat1` are you referring to? Also the call to `NF90_PUT_VAR` is incorrect. There's no `values` array in the call. Further, you have defined your file to be in netCDF classic format. You can't have multiple unlimited dimensions in that format. Please check all your status values like Mark says above. Writing a short error handling routine will help immensely.

Comment: Sir, up to NF90_DEF_VAR function call it is executing correctly, Since I am printing stat values and it is giving output 0 (zero). But I am unable to execute my NF90_PUT_VAR(ncid_user,ev_id,e)  function correctly.